# How do a write and read a string value to/from UIPasteboard in iOS?

Tags: ios

I have the following test, failing

```
NSString * expectedValue = @"achilles";

UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard pasteboardWithName:@"pb1" create:YES];
pasteboard.persistent = YES;

pasteboard.string = expectedValue;    
STAssertEqualObjects(expectedValue, [pasteboard string], @"get written value from pasteboard");

[pasteboard setString:expectedValue];
STAssertEqualObjects(expectedValue, [pasteboard string], @"get written value from pasteboard");
```

Both of the asserts fail,

```
'achilles' should be equal to '(null)'
```

Am I incorrectly writing to the pasteboard, reading from the pasteboard, or both?

Comment: Try logging the value of `pasteboard` to make sure it is created properly. You're not using the reverse DNS naming scheme suggested in the docs, everything else looks ok, though. If this is inside a unit test, you may not be able to create a pasteboard, since it isn't running within an application?

Comment: Logging the value of the pasteboard also shows nil, and changeCount shows -1.  `NSLog(@"pasteboard.string: %@, changeCount: %d", pasteboard.string, pasteboard.changeCount);` shows: `pasteboard.string: (null), changeCount: -1`. I tried using the reverse DNS naming scheme, same result.  It is running inside of a unittest.

Comment: I meant log the actual pasteboard object, to ensure it is created correctly and is not nil.

Comment: Logging pasteboard object confirms it is not nil: `<UIPasteboard: 0x1b48130>`

Comment: Your exact code works fine for me (Xcode 4.4, iOS5.1 SDK).

Comment: did you ever get an answer for this?

Comment: What environment is this code running, SDK's unit tests?

Comment: Why are you using a custom pasteboard `pb1`? Try `[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard]` Unless you need the custom pasteboard for a reason I don't know about O:)

Comment: Also the fact that you say `pb1" create:YES];` makes me very suspicious that it might be over-writing any data that may have been in pb1... try setting `create` to `NO`

Answer (score 0):

I assume the problem is the following:
The `string` property of `UIPasteboard` is defined as ([see the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPasteboard_Class/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008243-CH1-SW30))

```
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *string;
```

This means that if you assign a string to it, it will be copied, i.e. a new object is created. When you read it back and compare it to the original object, the compare must fail.

Comment: But the assert says 'achilles' should be equal to '(null)'

Answer (score -1):

If  you are writing or reading a string from UIPasteBoard you can easily do it by accessing,

```
   [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard].string = @"your string";

   NSString *str =  [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard].string];
```

Answer (score -1):

For reading and writing `NSString` you can use general paste board.

there are two simple ways to **write**...

```
//Method 1
NSString * str=@"your String";
UIPasteboard * pasteboard=[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
[pasteboard setString:];

//Method 2
NSData *data = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[pasteboard setData:data forPasteboardType:(NSString *)kUTTypeText];
```

and you can **read** `NSString` as bellow

```
   UIPasteboard * pasteboard=[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];

    //Method 1
    NSLog(@"Text =%@",[pasteboard string]);

    //Method 2
    NSData * data = [pasteboard dataForPasteboardType:(NSString*)kUTTypeText];
    NSString * str =[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"str =%@",str);
```

For more info you can [refer this Blog](http://hayageek.com/uipasteboard-example-read-write-share/)

Answer (score -1):

Your code passed the testing in Unit Testing. You should point out your development environment if you did have trouble in it.

> Test Case '-[TestTests testExample]' started.
>   Test Case '-[TestTests testExample]' passed (0.001 seconds).

Tested in Xcode 5.1.1 with SDK iOS7.1

Comment: Are you testing an application here, or an SDK? For me it only happens when I am unit testing an SDK

Comment: Just copy & paste your code to a test case example. If you have additional note, you should edit your question to list it there.